# Strict concavity when Hessian is only negative semi-definite for some values?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am trying to find the values of *a* and *b* for which the function $f(x,y)=x^a+y^b$ is strictly concave over non-negative x and y.

At first I was using the method of evaluating the definiteness of the Hessian. I got that the leading principal minor of order one is $a(a-1)x^{a-2}$ and the leading principal minor of order two is $a(a-1)b(b-1)x^{a-2}y^{b-2}$. Since the first must be negative and the second must be positive, this should require both $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$.

But then I started wondering whether this solution is only valid for the domain where $x$ and $y$ are both strictly positive. What happens if $x=y=0$? How do I make an argument that $f(x,y)$ is strictly concave for $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$ over its whole domain? The Hessian is not negative definite at $x=y=0$, but since negative definiteness is only a sufficient condition and not a necessary condition, that doesn't rule out strict concavity there, right? Should I somehow appeal to the definition of strict concavity?

Comment: You have to examine not only the case when both $x = 0$ and $y = 0$, but also when only one of those two cases holds while the other variable is free to change. But those cases are actually not hard to see, as they are 1-dimensional. $f(x, 0) = x^a, f(0, y) = y^b$, which are easy to check for concavity. At (0, 0) you just need to finess things a bit, but if you think about what concavity means physically, you can see that it is impossible to fail at a single point. It should be fairly easy to apply the definition to handle this case.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I see it very easily using the definition the for (x,0) and (0,y) cases, but as said in the original post, I am still struggling to make a formal argument for the (0,0) case. I will think about it more, I guess.